# Does a Network-Switch changes TCP-Packages?

Tags: switch

I am investigating a network issue, where our driver(s) under VxWorks7 is generating errors-messages like:

"Notice: resend delayed, network driver has not finished the previous TX attempt on this package: socket: 394, segment 1009313362, time: 223644250" and "out of mBlks…"

There are two network devices of different vendors (and different drivers). With both i get those messages. The first one is a build-in imx6 network interface by freescale/nxp. The second is a intel card. For the first one, i know, that there is an errata, that this card is only capable of 400MBit/s. This is manage in the driver via pause-frames. Both cards connected to a Gigabit network.

I increased the related buffers and tried to tweek the driver, so that i see changed behaviour in the error-messages - but i don't.

The interesting part is, that those messages (problems) are only comming up, if i have two network-switches between me and the device.

me --- switch1 --- switch2 --- device

I get the problem also if i replace "switch2". Again, without "switch2", there is no problem.

In my understanding, the switch is transparent to the network-packages. Only the latency should be visible.

Does anyone have an idea in wich direction i should go with further investigations?

Comment: Switches switch frames based on the frame header and do not concern themselves with the frame payload.

Comment: Update the switch Firmware as first option in my point of View.